# Inline comment directives to coverage and to flake8

Tags: python, code-coverage

Assume I have the following `__init__py`:

```
# __init__.py
from . import my_foo
```

Just like so, `flake8` would complain with `F401`. This can be resolved by:

```
# __init__.py
from . import my_foo  # NOQA: F401
```

On the other hand, `cov` plugin of `pytest` would complain that there are no tests for this line. This can be resolved by:

```
# __init__.py
from . import my_foo  # pragma: no cover
```

How can I make both happy? I could do something like:

```
# flake8: noqa
from . import gender  # pragma: no cover
```

But this influences the whole file from `flake8`'s perspective.

I also tried something like:

```
from . import gender  # pragma: no cover, NOQA: F401
```

But it didn't work as expected.

Comment: Try this: `# pragma: no cover NOQA: F401`

Comment: @Dekel It fixes the coverage issue but `flake8` is complaining. I tried the other order and I got the reversed problem ;)

Answer (score 5):

The comment syntax for coverage.py is configurable. You can override the regexes that lines are matched against: [Advanced Exclusion](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/excluding.html#advanced-exclusion)

For example:

```
[report]
exclude_lines =
    pragma: no cover
```

This will match any line containing "pragma: no cover", so this comment should now work:

```
# NOQA: F401; pragma: no cover
```

The default regex requires only space between the "#" and "pragma"